# can it be said that NL^NL = NL?

Tags: complexity-theory

I was wondering if it can be said that $\mbox{NL}^\mbox{NL}=\mbox{NL}$. That is, a decision problem  $S$ can be decided using a nondeterministic TM using logarithmic space with oracle calls to $S'\in \mbox{NL}$ iff $S\in \mbox{NL}$.

My intuition is yes, because if $S'\in \mbox{NL}$ then there is a NDTM $M$ that decides it in logarithmic space. And so one can use the NDTM $M'$ for $S$ but every oracle call will be simulated on $M$, preserving the logarithmic space constraint.

I am not sure if this approach is correct, and if it is, how to formally explain such an algorithm for the simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry, it's not my area, so I'm not confident, but it should be correct)

Yes. Moreover, you can assume that your oracle requires memory which depends linearly on the input size.

One way to define oracles is to assume that you have a main tape $T_1$ (or many such tapes) and a special tape $T_2$ such that you can write on this tape, and in one step solve the problem on this tape. This happens when we arrive into a special state $Q$, and after oracle computation it changes into new state $R$.

**Machine construction**:
Let $M$ be a "main" TM. Let $M'$ be a TM for our oracle with starting state $S$ and final state $F$. I assume that machines' sets of states $S_M$ and $S_{M'}$ are disjoint. Then we build an oracle-less machine the following way:

- Our new states are the following: $(S_M \setminus \{Q\}) \cup (S_{M'} \setminus \{F\})$.
- When we work on $T_1$ (current state is in $S_M$), our rules ignore symbols on $T_2$ and also don't update $T_2$ in any way. Similarly when we work with $T_2$.
- When we should arrive at $Q$ in $M$, we instead arrive at $S$ (starting state of $M'$). Similarly, when we should arrive at $F$ in $M'$, we instead arrive at $R$.

**Answering your question**:
If $M$ requires logarithmic space, and $M'$ requires linear space, then the resulting machine is in $NL$:

- We only use logarithmic space on $T_1$.
- During execution of $M$ (when we work on $T_1$), the algorithm can write only $O(\log n)$ memory on $T_2$ (since we assume that $M$ requires logarithmic amount of memory). After that, since $M'$ can use memory which linearly depends on the input size, it also requires $O(\log n)$ memory. After execution of $M'$, $T_2$ has $O(1)$ size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am working with a 3 tape model: input tape, work tape, and output tape.  From my understanding you're working with two work tapes. Are the models equivalent?

Comment: I'm not sure if they are equivalent when the *time* is concerned, but they are certainly equivalent when *space* is concerned (i.e. our case): you can just store both tapes on one tape with a special separator between them.

Comment: Time really isn't an issue. How would you separate the two computations when they're varying in size? After all, it's $O(\log n)$ and the exact amount of space is not known. I can't seem to wrap my head around that.

Comment: For any computation (not only for $O(\log n)$ memory) you can separate them. You store the separator in fixed position, and the first tape is on the left, and the second one is on the right. When one sequence tries to extend itself to the separator, you just shift this sequence by one position in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite as simple. Calls to oracle have a "magic" quality of taking only one unit of time. Even if NL can simulate the oracle calls, these simulated invocations of the oracle can take more resources than is needed by the oracle machine. To prove these classes equal you need to prove that calls to the oracle do not improve performance in the computational complexity sense because producing the input to the oracle already requires sufficient resources that the oracle machine cannot use this "magic" to get improved performance.